# API to determine sharepoint site's search setting

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

Is it possible to determine the search setting for a sharepoint site (i.e. whether the site is allowed to appear in search results) using any sharepoint API (graph/rest/soap)?

Comment: I am not aware (such feature exists or exposed to developers) in any of the APIs which are available in Office 365s Enterprise Search center.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware (such feature exists or exposed to developers) in any of the APIs which are available in Office 365s Enterprise Search center. Being said that you can create a [new Microsoft User voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/category/359620-sites-and-lists-sharepoint/filters/top?page=3), so that they can consider implementing it.